# What is the best way to add a Javascript component to speak?

Tags: sitecore-client, speak, javascript

I want to use the jsgrid in a customized sitecore shell model , i wonder what could be the best way to include the script file without building a custom speak component.

Thank you

Comment: Is this for a Speak Application that you are building?

Comment: No , i want to fix a client page and i am wondering if my approach was the optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  I know you said a custom SPEAK component, but I thought I provide various ways of adding JS into Sitecore:

1. [Read my blog](https://marcotanainsights.wordpress.com/2017/10/12/add-placeholder-name-when-inserting-sitecore-component-without-updating-sitecore-js-files/) where I include the name of the placeholder on the "Add here" button in Experience Editor.  I don't think this is what you need but should give you some ideas.
2. If you are using the PageCode rendering, there's a PageCodeScriptFilename that you use to load a JS file.  See this [Sitecore walkthrough for details](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details).
3. Use a SPEAK client pipeline.  Take a [look at this example](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2017/03/24/sitecore-experience-ribbon-header/).